# python panda read_table, IOError file does not exist

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a string s to a dataframe.

```
s='185662748,9359839,155872098,13.99,72\r\n185662748,9359839,155872098,15.58,75\r\n185662748,9359839,155872098,126.99,94\r\n'
```

I used this `df=pd.read_table(s,sep=',',lineterminator='\n',header=header).`

But it returns me

> "IOError: File 185662748,9359839,155872098,13.99,72
>   .... does not exist"

I want to convert sting to output as below as direct as possible:

```
a     b          c       d          e

0  185662748  9359839  155872098   13.99  72

1  185662748  9359839  155872098   15.58  75

2  185662748  9359839  155872098  126.99  94
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read_table` expects either a filename or a file-like object. If you pass a string, it expects it to be a filename. You can wrap a string in a `StringIO` object to make it behave like a file instead, allowing you
to use the string directly:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

s='185662748,9359839,155872098,13.99,72\r\n185662748,9359839,155872098,15.58,75\r\n185662748,9359839,155872098,126.99,94\r\n'

pd.read_table(StringIO(s), sep=',', header=None)
Out[10]: 
           0        1          2       3   4
0  185662748  9359839  155872098   13.99  72
1  185662748  9359839  155872098   15.58  75
2  185662748  9359839  155872098  126.99  94
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. a quick summary:

1) import StringIO is necessary.

2) "header" requires int, to declare column location

3) "names" declares column name.

source 2), 3):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_table.html